# Передать ссылку из активити в фрагмент без конструктора

Tags: java, android, android-fragment

Каким образом можно передать ссылку на конкретный объект из активити в фрагмент?

В методе `onCreateView()` фрагмента ссылка безбожно обнуляется, хотя доходит до фрагмента и сетится как таковая(так говорят логи, во всяком случае).

Зачем нужно - ресайкл вью находится внутри фрагмента, в каждом элементе этого списка имеется кнопка "инфо", по нажатию на которую нужно выводить bottom sheet(из последнего обновления библиотеки поддержки), и я путаюсь во всей этой вложенности.

Искал примеры реализации интерфейсов колбеков - но в основном они на то, что-бы слушать активити из фрагмента.

Признаюсь, дела с интерфейсами у меня совсем не очень, поэтому попросту не знаю, как это должно выглядеть.

Подскажите подробным кодом, сама идея мне ясна, проблема с реализацией.

ps. Уточню, что фрагмент менеджер нигде не использую, и фрагмент "достается" таким вот способом

[image: Метод получения инстанса фрагмента]

Comment: Не нужно делать скриншотов с кодом, код должен быть оформлен, как текст.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передача ссылки на объект через интерфейс:

1) Фрагмент (определяет интерфейс `PassMeLinkOnObject` ):

```
public class MainActivityFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView tv1;
    PassMeLinkOnObject activity;

    public interface PassMeLinkOnObject {
        String getStringObject();
        //AClass getAClass(); //Методов (и передаваемых объектов) м.б. несколько
    }

    public MainActivityFragment() {
    }

    public static MainActivityFragment getInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        MainActivityFragment fragment = new MainActivityFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        activity = (PassMeLinkOnObject)getActivity();  //!!!!!
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        tv1 = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv1);
        String s = activity.getStringObject();  //!!!!!
        tv1.setText(s);
        return view;
    }
}
```

2) Активность (реализует интерфейс `PassMeLinkOnObject` ):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
MainActivityFragment.PassMeLinkOnObject{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment == null) {
           fragment = new MainActivityFragment();

           fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragment_container, fragment)
                .commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getStringObject() {
        return "String";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Фрагмент надо получать из фрагмент менеджер-а.

Код в активити:

```
RecyclerFragment frag = (RecyclerFragment )getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.ID_КОНТЕЙНЕРА_В_КОЕМ_ЛЕЖИТ_ФРАГМЕНТ);

if(frag!=null)
{
    //тут ваш фрагмент. Вызывайте его методы тут
}
else
{
    Log.e("Tag", "fragment is null");
    //до обращения к фрагменту он должен быть отображён.
    //в onResume это наверняка будет так. 
    //в onCreate фрагмента ещё не будет в мэнеджере.
}
```

Comment: То есть при создании фрагмента через менеджер, я смогу сетить нужную ссылку и он не будет обнулять ее?

Comment: @Asgard, чрез менеждер нельзя создать фрагмент. Можно только оперировать ими. В данном случае вы лишь получаете ссылку на фрагмент.

Comment: а как же статический метод из самого фрагмента?гетИнстанс - что в таком случае он делает?

Comment: @Asgard, он создаёт объект фрагмента и возвращает его. Вы можете фрагмент так созданный отобразить(добавить) в активити через менеждер.

Comment: я постараюсь сделать, как вы посоветовали, на днях отпишусь как получилось.
Спасибо за отклик, не взирая на результат.